# How to add angular code inside markup add by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular2-template

I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {

var options = {
  float: true
};

$('.grid-stack').gridstack(options);

this.gridHr = $('.grid-stack-hr').data('gridstack');

this.items.filter(i => i.category == 'hr').map( item => {
      this.gridHr.addWidget($(`<div class="start-grid-stack-item">
        <div class="grid-stack-item-content"  style="background:${ item.color }">
          <a class="link" [routerLink]="['employee']">
            <img style="display: ${ item.icon ? 'inline-block': 'none' }" src="assets/gridstack/${ item.icon }">
            <p>${ item.title }</p>            
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>`),
      item.x, item.y, item.width, item.height);
    });

}
```

I am using jQuery plugin inside angular application. but I am not able to use angular constructs like `[routerLink]="['employee']` inside html code add by jQuery.

Is that even possible ?

Use any code that showcase usage of angular inside code added by jQuery.

Comment: If you do your changes before your angular app is initialized, it should work.  Alternatively, you might check if https://github.com/linagora/dynamic-directive will do the trick for you.

Comment: I am using angular 2

Comment: Ah ... I don't know angular 2 well enough to help much, then.